# Store and reuse BeautifulSoup searches and node traversals

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm building a utility to pull similar data (title and date) from a bunch of differently-formatted sites, and BeautifulSoup has been very helpful. I haven't figured out a good way to store the BeautifulSoup functions I'm using so that I don't have to build a new function for each site. Here's an example:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
title = soup.find("h4", "title").text    # extract title
date = soup.find('li', 'when').em.text       # extract date
```

Each site is going to have a different set of nodes to parse. With hundreds of sites, it'd be silly to build a unique function for each. Is there a way to store the soup.find('x').etc.etc calls in a table alongside the URLs and just apply the correct BeautifulSoup call within one function? Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be misunderstanding your question, but can't you just create a function that takes in parameters?

Comment: I can pass the contents of the find() in, but how do I specify the nodes afterwards? For example, the title just uses .text, but the date uses .em.text. I'm probably going to need to traverse different nodes in the tree for each site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, assuming I understand your post, would this work?

```
linkInstructions = {
  "url1": {
    "title": lambda n: n.find('h4', 'title').text,
    "date": lambda n: n.find('li', 'when').em.text
  },
  "url2": {
    "title": lambda n: n.find('h3', 'title').text,
    "date": lambda n: n.find('li', 'when').strong.text
  }
  # and so forth
} 

def parseNode(node, url):
  # let 'node' be the result of BeautifulSoup(html)
  # and 'url' be the url of the site    

  result = {}

  for key,func in linkInstructions[url].iteritems():
    result[key] = func(node)

  # would return a dict with the structure {'title': <title>, 'date': <date>}
  return result
```

Edit: Oops, enumerate isn't the right function to use.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely has me on the right track - I wasn't aware of lambda functions. This works when I define the dict with the lambda functions in code, but when I try to store them (I'm using a db.StringProperty() in Google App Engine's datastore), I get `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`. I tried storing the dict using repr(), but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know much about Google App Engine, is that a serialization function? As in it converts the dict to a string? I think what might be happening is that when you turn it back into dict, you turn the outside dict (`linkInstructions`) back into a dict, but the inner dicts (the ones for each URL) stay strings. So you're going to have to cycle twice: first deserialize the outer dict, then deserialize the inner dicts. 

This is just a guess however. Try printing the dict and seeing what you get.